# Win Form Application Runs a Method Everyday Even If It is Not Running

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, winforms

I have a VB .Net Windows Form application with MS SQL server for database part of it. I need to run a method which essentially depending on some date sensitive data in the database may or may not create a notification email to be sent to one or more recipients. This application may not be used everyday. So ideally I don't want that method to be bound to let say Form Load of the main Form. How can this be achieved?

Comment: A Windows Service or a Scheduled Task are the traditional approaches.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably don't want that logic in your client application. There are three ways that come to mind:

1. put the logic in the SQL Server and create a job that is scheduled to run every day
2. create a small utility application and schedule that to once each day
3. create a windows service that runs all the time and handles these jobs for you

If all the data necessary to make the determination of whether or not to send the notification e-mails is available in the database, and you have access to create a job on the SQL server, I would recommend that route.

However if there are external components that you need in order to make the determinations or to send the e-mails then either approach 2 or 3 will be the way to go. Creating an application and scheduling it to run each day would be easier to implement but a service has the benefit of not requiring an interactive logon session (i.e. doesn't need a user to be actively logged in on the computer) which is preferable on a server.